# Why does Python cron cant write text file in order to time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, cron

I write a code about in python. It gathers crontab times from the user in ui. Then user have to write a text. And that text write in the txt file, in order to crontab time. But the text file wont working. It writes the time but no text. Just "None". I think the error should be there:

I tried to give permissions, py file and txt file in same folder, asking to chat gpt and google. Step by step looking at the code but cant find the answer.

```py
def get_report_text():
    report_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    report_window.title("Rapor Metni Girin")
    
    report_label = tk.Label(report_window, text="Rapor Metni:")
    report_label.pack()

    report_entry = tk.Entry(report_window, width=50)
    report_entry.pack()

    def save_report():
        report_text = report_entry.get()
        if report_text:
            report_window.destroy()
            return report_text
        else:
            messagebox.showwarning("Uyarı", "Lütfen bir rapor metni girin.")

    save_button = tk.Button(report_window, text="Kaydet", command=save_report)
    save_button.pack()

    report_window.wait_window()

def on_generate_button_click():
    try:
        minute, hour, day_of_month, month, day_of_week = get_crontab_input()
        crontab_expression = generate_crontab_expression(minute, hour, day_of_month, month, day_of_week)
        human_readable_expression = crontab_to_human_readable(crontab_expression)

        report_text = get_report_text()

        output_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Desktop", "output.txt")

        threading.Thread(target=schedule_job, args=(crontab_expression, report_text, output_path)).start()

        result_text = f"Son Kullanıcı: {human_readable_expression}"
        result_label.config(text=result_text)

    except ValueError as e:
        messagebox.showerror("Hata", f"{e}")
    except Exception as e:
        messagebox.showerror("Hata", f"Bir hata oluştu: {e}")
```

Comment: The method `get_report_text()` does not `return` a value and thus implicitly returns `None` and that is why `report_text` is `None`.